# how to bypass workflow rule

Tags: salesforce, workflow, event-triggers

"i have an object and we have written a workflow and as well as trigger on the same object and my question is how to Bypass workflow rule with out deactivating workflow, only trigger has to work.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom field on the object record that can be toggled on/off. You could setup multiple fields to bypass Validation Rules, Workflow Rules, Triggers.

Then include a criteria for the running user e.g.
In a workflow rule have current object: val rules on = false or if using a formula $Object.Val_Rule_on__c = TRUE